# How to handle composite type of Entities using RASA NLU?

Tags: python, nlp, rasa-nlu

Let's say I have this utterance: "**My name is John James Doe**"

```
{
    "rasa_nlu_data": {
        "common_examples": 
        [
          {
             "text": "My name is John James Doe",
             "intent": "Introduction",
             "entities": [
                           {
                              "start": 11,
                              "end": 25,
                              "value": "John James Doe",
                              "entity": "Name"
                           }
                         ]
                    }
        ],
        "regex_features" : [],
        "entity_synonyms": []
    }
}
```

Here the substring `John James Doe` is a composite entity of type `Name` having 3 simple entities (`First Name`, `Middle Name`, `Last Name`) as follows:

- **John - First Name(Simple Entity)**
- **James - Middle Name(Simple Entity)**
- **Doe - Last Name(Simple Entity)**

So, is there any in RASA for me to make a training format which will handle these kinds of composite type of entities.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have an easier time if you continue to train with an entity type of Name that pulls out a section of text for all the names and then try to process the individual composite parts from the returned entity text. The reason being if you try to train on the component parts, you'll quickly have to provide a whole raft of combinations in your training data and that will become ineffective.

Also bear in mind that this isn't a trivial problem as you go deeper. If you use position alone to determine first / middle / last, you may have problems in Japan (https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/names-for-people.html ) and if you tried to train to recognise names based on content (ie to pick out Doe as a last name) it will be prone to problems: it's not unknown for Americans to have first names that elsewhere are thought of as last names (Jackson, Hunter etc), middle names vary a lot too (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_name )

Comment: I agree that it is very western-centric to assume all names follow the personal-middle-family pattern... however, there do exist situations where compound entities are a good abstraction

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [custom component](https://github.com/BeWe11/rasa_composite_entities) for this as I needed composite entities as well. Here is a summary of how it works.

Let's say your training data rather looked like this:

```
    "rasa_nlu_data": {
        "common_examples": 
        [
          {
             "text": "My name is John James Doe",
             "intent": "Introduction",
             "entities": [
                           {
                              "start": 11,
                              "end": 15,
                              "value": "John",
                              "entity": "first_name"
                           },
                           {
                              "start": 16,
                              "end": 21,
                              "value": "James",
                              "entity": "middle_name"
                           },
                           {
                              "start": 22,
                              "end": 25,
                              "value": "Doe",
                              "entity": "last_name"
                           },
                         ]
                    }
        ],
        "regex_features" : [],
        "entity_synonyms": []
    }
}
```

So instead of training the full name as an entity that will be split, you train name parts that will be grouped to full names.

The basic idea now is that you define composite patterns with entity placeholders. For your example, you could define this pattern:

```
full_name = "@first_name @middle_name @last_name"
```

For your example sentence, Rasa NLU will recognize the three entities in it like this:

```
My name is    John       James       Doe
               ^           ^          ^
           first_name middle_name last_name
```

You take the input sentence and replace every recognized entity with its entity type:

```
My name is @first_name @middle_name @last_name
```

You can now perform a simple check whether your defined pattern is included in this string.

```
My name is @first_name @middle_name @last_name
                            ^
                            | Pattern matches
                            |
           "@first_name @middle_name @last_name"
```

If it is included, you take all entities values that are part of the inclusion and group them together to a full_name.

```
My name is John           James        Doe           
                            ^
                            | Pattern matches
                            |
           @first_name @middle_name @last_name


-> full_name = ["John", "James", "Doe"]
```

If you use regular expressions instead of simple string matching, you can make this system a lot more flexible. For example, you could make the middle name optional by changing your pattern to

```
full_name = "@first_name (@middle_name )?@last_name"
```

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and read the section: "**Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much**". You shouldn't talk about your own products or at least down mark them as your own.

Comment: Hey Aaron, thanks for the heads-up and the link. I've added a description of how my code works to avoid having a single link as an answer. I still think my answer is valid because it a) provides a direct solution to the problem and b) I'm linking to open-source code, I'm not selling a product. I hope by providing a description I'm not violating any rules anymore.